# Mounted path to CSV-File returns directory, os isfile check returns False

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage, databricks

When trying to navigate in Databricks to a specfic folder/file combination using `os`, 2 identical csv's get randomly recognized as `file` or `directory`.
When checking with `os.path.isfile()`, the following returns:

[image]

So far I tried re-loading the data, checking if there were any problems with the specific csv's and can't seem to find a pattern as to which file this error will occur with.
I tried following advice listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52338706/isadirectoryerror-errno-21-is-a-directory-it-is-a-file) but the error seems Databricks-specifc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution I found was reading data using `spark` :

```
  df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv') \
          .options(header='true', inferSchema='true', sep=';')\
          .load("/mnt/.../.../.../data_2.csv").toPandas()
```

This will read the data from the `csv` fine - yet checking with `os.path.isfile()` still doesn't recognize the file as a file.