# why am i getting this IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21]?

Tags: python, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

```
download_images(path/file, dest, max_pics=400)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IsADirectoryError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-fd768bad6ac9> in <module>()
      1 #3
----> 2 download_images(path/file, dest, max_pics=400)

2 frames
/usr/lib/python3.6/pathlib.py in open(self, mode, buffering, encoding, errors, newline)
   1181             self._raise_closed()
   1182         return io.open(str(self), mode, buffering, encoding, errors, newline,
-> 1183                        opener=self._opener)
   1184 
   1185     def read_bytes(self):

IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'data/marvel/thor'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“IsADirectoryError: \[Errno 21\] Is a directory: ” It is a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52338706/isadirectoryerror-errno-21-is-a-directory-it-is-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

If `data/marvel/thor` is a directory, please try follows.

```
import os
data_paths = [os.path.join(pth, f) for pth, dirs, files in os.walk('data/marverl/thor') for f in files]
data = [download_images(f, mmap_mode='r') for f in data_paths]
```

You need to provide a variable/place to store each image separately.