# Processing files with listdir() breakes when directory contains subdirectories

Tags: python, file, directory

Following code should walk through directory and grab XML files and process them (i.e. prefixing HTML classes stored in XML elements — however, this is not important in relation to the question). The code works as long as there are no subdirectories inside "/input-dir", but as soon as there are subdirectories, an error message gets thrown out:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/ab/Code/SHCprefixer-2022/shc-prefixer_upwork.py", line 22, in  content = file.readlines(); File "/codecs.py", line 322, in decode (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 566: invalid start byte

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os
import lxml
import re

input_path = "./input-dir";
output_path = "./output-dir";

ls = os.listdir(input_path);
print(ls);

with open("classes.txt", "r") as cls:
    clss = cls.readlines()
    for i in range(len(clss)):
        clss[i] = clss[i].strip()
print(clss);

for d in range(len(ls)):

    with open(f"{input_path}/{ls[d]}", "r") as file:
        content = file.readlines();
        content = "".join(content)
        bs_content = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
        str_bs_content = str(bs_content)
        str_bs_content = str_bs_content.replace("""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><html><body>""", "");
        str_bs_content = str_bs_content.replace("</body></html>", "");
        for j in range(len(clss)):
            str_bs_content = str_bs_content.replace(clss[j], f"prefix-{clss[j]}")
    with open(f"{output_path}/{ls[d]}", "w") as f:
        f.write(str_bs_content)
```

Probably the error is related to the listdir() command, and as indicated in ["IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: " It is a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52338706/isadirectoryerror-errno-21-is-a-directory-it-is-a-file), I should use `os.walk()`, but I wasn't able to implement it. Would be great if someone could help.

Comment: Do you want to walk through all of the subdirectories too?

Comment: Yes! And it would be best if only XML files are processed to avoid issues.

Comment: You don't really know they are xml files without trying. Unless you want to assume that its just everything with ".xml" extensions. Is that okay?

Comment: Yes, that would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test whether the returned file system name is a file. You also want to search the entire subtree. Instead of `listdir` you could use `os.walk`, but I think that the newer `pathlib` module better suites your needs. Its `.glob` method, when used with "**", will search the subtree and filter for a known file extension at the same time.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import lxml
import re
from pathlib import Path

input_path = Path("./input-dir")
output_path = Path("./output-dir")

ls = [p for p in input_path.glob("**/*.xml") if p.is_file()]
print(", ".join(str(p) for p in ls))

with open("classes.txt", "r") as cls:
    clss = cls.readlines()
    for i in range(len(clss)):
        clss[i] = clss[i].strip()
print(clss)

for infile in ls:
    with infile.open() as file:
        bs_content = BeautifulSoup(file.read(), "lxml")
        str_bs_content = str(bs_content)
        str_bs_content = str_bs_content.replace("""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><html><body>""", "");
        str_bs_content = str_bs_content.replace("</body></html>", "");
        for j in range(len(clss)):
            str_bs_content = str_bs_content.replace(clss[j], f"prefix-{clss[j]}")
    outfile = output_path / infile.relative_to(input_path)
    outfile.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    with outfile.open("w") as f:
        f.write(str_bs_content)
```

Comment: There's an error thrown out because the output-directory structure doesn't exist, it has to be generated (only the top folder exists from the beginning): ```File "/Users/ab/Code/SHCprefixer-2022/shc-prefixer_stacko2.py", line 28, in <module>
    with outfile.open("w") as f:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/pathlib.py", line 1119, in open
    return self._accessor.open(self, mode, buffering, encoding, errors,
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'output-dir/studium-d/scales.xml'```

Comment: @Madamadam - I updated to create directories. Hopefully that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you will need to filter out directories from the input path dir. You could use `os.path.isfile(x)` to check it. Using list comprehension you can get the filtered list in one line:

```
ls = [f for f in os.listdir(input_path) if os.path.isfile(f)]
```